# Como puedo utilizar esta función para una variable int

Tags: c

Esta función   es para una variable tipo char pero no se como cambiarla para poder utilizarla en una variable int estaba pensando que  en el arreglo dinámico utilizar un itoa o atoi pero al momento de hacerlo no funciona

```
char *leerId(char *msg){//control cedula 10 digitos y solo numeros
    int i=0,j=0,x=0;
    char *id=(char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));

    do{
        printf("%s",msg);
        scanf("%s",id); fflush(stdin);

            if(strlen(id)!=10){
                 x=0;
            }else{
                for(i=0; i<strlen(id);i++){
                     if(isdigit(id[i])){
                         x=1;
                    }else{
                        x=0;
                    }
                }
            }
    }while(x==0);

    return id;
}
```

No sesi le sirve pero cuando la quiero utilizar me sale este error
[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
Lo mas posible es que pase esto por lo que la utilizo para un int y estaba pensando en convetir en un array de enteros

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que la función devuelva un entero? Puedes usar `scanf("%d", &variable)`. Por cierto, [el comportamiento de `fflush` no está definido para streams de entrada](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/13419694). Mejor usa [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) o `fgetc` para descartar los caracteres que quieras.

Comment: digo que la pueda utilizar para una variable  que sea tipo int ya que así me sirve para char pero no sabría la forma exacta de como convertirla para que funcione con una variable tipo int

Comment: No sería simplemente `int cedula` y leerla con `scanf("%d", &cedula)` lo que estás preguntando? Claro que entonces ya no puedes verificar caracter a caracter lo que ha introucido. Tal vez solo quieres que la función, aunque lea la cadena, retorne el entero. En ese caso, `return atoi(cedula)`

Comment: Por cierto, el comportamiento de `fflush(stdin)` es indefinido. No vacía la entrada estándar (y si lo hace, usando otro compilador podría ya no hacerlo)